# How to add a menu tab to a user profile?

Tags: 7, users, routes

I want to create an additional tab (dashboard) on my site's user profile page. There is a [Homebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/homebox) module installed and a dashboard was created for users. The dashboard is accessible by user/dashboard. How can I do this? I tried doing it as below:

1. New module created with name add_menu_tab
2. In add_menu_tab.module file I wrote as below
   I want to create an additional tab (dashboard) on my site's user profile page. There is a homebox module installed and a dashboard was created for users. The dashboard is accessible by user/dashboard. How can I do this? I tried doing it as below:
3. New module created with name add_menu_tab
4. In add_menu_tab.module file I wrote as below:

code :

```
function add_menu_tab_menu() {
     $items['user/dashboard'] = array(
    'title' => 'Dashboard',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'weight' => 7
    );
    return $items;
  }
```

The menu is still not visible in user profile
What should I do?

Comment: Have you cleared menu cache? It's what I usually forget to do.

Comment: I surely cleared menu cache... Still the menu tab is not visible in user profile page...

Answer (score 2):

You should implement [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) instead of hook_menu.

```
function add_menu_tab_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/dashboard']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;
}
```

Then you should clear the cache, at least the menu cache, as Mołot suggested.

There is also another approach using [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7). But the first method is better since it is called only once, after the hook_menu and saved in the database, while the latter is being called each time the local tasks are rendered.

Answer (score 2):

As you said dashboard is created and accessible in `user/dashboard` ,all you need to do is in your custom module  altering menu by `hook_menu_alter` ([menu alter API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)) and changing the menu type to `MENU_LOCAL_TASk` .

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['user/dashboard']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;
}
```

**Remember to clear cache afterward ;)**